# utilizar metodos de uma classe em outra

Tags: java

estou fazendo uma aplicação simples, e na hora de usar os métodos de uma classe em outra, não está dando certo.

tenho as seguinte classe:

```
    import org.bson.Document;
    import com.github.fakemongo.Fongo;
    import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

    public class Model {
        Fongo fongo = new Fongo("mongo");


        public void addEmpresario(Document user) {
            MongoDatabase db = fongo.getDatabase("antenas");
            MongoCollection<Document> empresario = db.getCollection("empresario");
            empresario.insertOne(user);
        }
   }
```

E a main, que por enquanto não possui nada. Como faço para chamar essa classe na main?

Comment: só você instanciar a classe na main **Model model = new Model()**, e dai pra você usar algum metodo da classe você usar **model.addEmpresario(parametros)**

Answer (score 0):

Vá na sua classe Main() e instancie a classe Model. Ex:

```
main(){
   Model model = new Model()
   model.addEmpresario(parametro)
}
```

não esqueça de dar um import do local da sua classe no começo do arquivo do main